# How to use list(intput()) elements in python?

Tags: string, list, numbers, uppercase, lowercase

Help, i need to ask for 2 words, then count the number of lowercase, uppercase, spaces and numbers. I was thinking of using list() to list each character and count them. Any ideas? thks

Comment: Please show what you've tried

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.